# Edit all worksheets except Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a script that deletes rows 1-4 on on every worksheet, but would like it to skip a worksheet if its name is "Sheet1"

```
Sub RowDelete()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Set xWs = ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Select
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Delete
    xWs.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it through a **FOR EACH Loop**:

```
Sub RowDelete()

    Dim xWs As Worksheet
        For Each xWs In Worksheets
            If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            xWs.Rows("1:4").Delete
            End If
    Next xWs
End Sub
```

Btw, try to learn coding without using .Select.